# How do I solve a system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I go about solving the two following systems of linear equations?

1.
$$\begin{align}
9x - 17y &= -20\\
-13x +  7y &= -94
\end{align}$$

2.
$$\begin{align}
5x - 2y &= -13\\
4x + 5y &=  -6
\end{align}$$

I come with the following wrong answers.

1. $x = -\dfrac75,  y = 3$
2. $x = 11, y = \dfrac5{46}$

Thank you.

Comment: We can be more helpful if you show your attempt at how you got those answers.

Comment: If you show your work we'll be able to correct your errors and that will be more helpful to you

Comment: For algebra like this, I would recommend using something like Symbolab or wolfram alpha if you want to check your work

Comment: You solve them by doing what your teacher taught you to do.  If noone ever taught you how, we'll be willing to teach you but it seems a waste of our time if some-one already has.  If someone has taught you, then show us your work and we'll point out where you made an error.  But there is no point in us just repeating what your teacher told you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straight forward way without a lot of mathematical background is to eliminate one variable first:

I will do the second problem as an example and leave the first for you:

We will eliminate $x$ by first multiplying both equations with a constant factor such that the coefficient for $x$ take the same value in the multiplied equations. Then we can eliminate $x$ by subtracting them:
$$20x-8y=-52$$
$$20x+25y=-30$$

We have multiplied the first equation by $4$
  and the second by $5$.

Now subtract them: $$-33y=-22$$

Thus $y=\frac{2}{3}$. Putting this in the second equation (or the first, which one does not matter) we get $4x+5\cdot\frac{2}{3}=-6$
  thus $x=-\frac{7}{3}$. We can use the other equation (here the first one) to test that we did not make an error in the calculation: $$-5\cdot\frac{7}{3}-2\cdot\frac{2}{3}=-\frac{35+4}{3}=-13$$
That is correct!

Note that a special case can occur when both equations eliminate to $0=0$
  when subtracting. In this case the equations are called "linear dependent" and there is an infinite amount of solution pairs for $\left(x,y\right)$
 ...

Remark: If you are serious about learning this, you should try to apply the exact same procedure to the first problem and update your question with your calculations in case any errors occur. You can also make up more problems and test yourself, again updateing your question in case of errors. This is the only way for you (and us) to make sure you have understood the procedure.